# PHP - where clause equals 2 values grabbed from URL is not showing any results?

Tags: php, sql, url

I am trying to get the results for a specific race at a specific meet.

```
raceresult.php?meet=<i>August Meet</i>&race=<i>Allowance Fillies 2yo</i>
```

The meet and race are showing up from the first query and some of the results show. For example:

THIS ONE WORKS

```
raceresult.php?meet=meet=2013 OJCR Australian Derby&race=Allowance - 9f on turf 3yo
```

DOES NOT WORK

```
raceresult.php?meet=2009 Gulfstream Park Grand Opening Meet&race=Flying Stakes - Grade I, 3 yr old+, 8F on dirt
```

Are there any characters causing an error in the second example? I can go through and fix that issue pretty easily but I'm not really sure what is keeping that URL from working while the other one works great.

My code is as follows.

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM racing WHERE `meet` = '$meet' LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() . "<br />" . $sql );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 

$date= $row['date'];
echo "<h2><strong>$meet</strong> ($date)</h2>";
echo "<b>$race</b><br>";
}
?>

<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM racing WHERE `meet`='$meet' and `race`='$race' ORDER BY place"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() . "<br />" . $sql );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 

$place= $row['place'];
$horse= $row['horse'];
$farm= $row['farm'];

echo"$place. $horse owned by $farm";

}
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Do not use this code until you've learned how to avoid this problem. If you get nothing from the second query, then investigate why. e.g. check `mysql_num_rows($query)`. If it's zero, then the query worked, but matched no rows.

Comment: Some of the information works but others do not. I added a link in my question to give an example of what just isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, when creating the GET variables for the URL, they should be passed through `urlencode` to convert the spaces into something that can be used.

Once in the script on this page, use `urldecode` to replace the encoded characters with their normal ones. (This bit might not be required - try it)

Then pass them through `mysql_escape_string` to make them play nice and lower the chance of SQL injection.

Try echoing the created `$sql` string to the screen or a log so that you can see *exactly* what is being attempted. This will help with making sure the GET variables are coming through correctly. Also, you can try running this SQL directly in a MySQL session to check that your SQL is correct.

Finally, stop using `mysql_` functions - they're deprecated. `mysqli_` or `PDO` is the way to o

Answer (score 0):

Your second URL is probaby incorrect, because `+` in a URL is decoded to a space character. You need to encode that `+` as `%2B` instead, so it'll be treated as a literal `+`, not a space character.

Since it's being mangled to space character, your query string will NEVER match, because you'll be comparing:

```
database:   ... Grade I, 3 yr old+, 8F ...
query   :   ... Grade I, 3 yr old , 8F ...
                                 ^---note the space
```